# Weird console outputs in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console

Some variable in local scope (inside IIFE function expression containing all code for JS file; "global" for this file) is holding values for pagination ranges.
It is having default values like:

```
PAGINATION_RANGES = [
    { start: 0, end: 0 },
    { start: 0, end: 0 }
];
```

Those values were changing on button click. Click was making GET request and in success block this variable was set with new ranges from server.

Change was made by editing variable directly like:

```
PAGINATION_RANGES[0].start = res.range[0].start; // 1
PAGINATION_RANGES[0].end = res.range[0].end; // 10
PAGINATION_RANGES[1].start = res.range[1].start; // 21
PAGINATION_RANGES[1].end = res.range[1].end // 30
```

for let's say range 11 - 20 on UI.

I know that I am making mutable changes on same variable (same reference is used) and I do not think there will be race conditions (default value is set when HTML and script file is loaded and it is changed only on click).

There is easy fix by replacing value each time with new array of objects, but I am wondering what is happening and why with this console output? 
This occurs in Firefox also.

[image]

Comment: Objects/Arrays in console are live objects not snapshots. Modifications made after the log statement will also be reflected

Comment: But there are no further modifications (only 1 button and 1 change of variable). Also values are changing back and forth as you can see on the image.

Comment: Every time you click on the button it modifies the object from the latest result. If you've already expanded the object in the console you'll continue to see that old value, but any time you close and re-expand you'll see the latest value.

Comment: Are all those `console.log()` calls done before or after the AJAX request?

Comment: Calls were done after AJAX immediately after object mutation.